# How can I effectively curve my items inside a list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I am trying to curve my list containing text inside of it.

I cannot effectively find a way to curve the items inside my list, for example my goal is to achieve something such as.

```
      () Text 
   () Text
 () Text
    () Text
      () Text
```

My initial idea was to create the `ul` inside a `div` and then for each `li` each the `left` CSS property to align everything, such as `left: 80`, then `left:60`, `left:40` then `left: 60`, `left: 80`. Unfortunately that did not work, nor does margins.

```
<div class="d-flex h-100 w-25 m-0 p-0 position-fixed align-items-center justify-content-center" style="background: transparent; left: 0;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <svg height="100" width="100" style="left: 20">  <-- Does not allow me to left:20 for some reason, but can allow me to left: 0 above?
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="3" fill="red"> </circle>
            </svg>
        </li>
       ....
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to create each list item containing a circle with text next to it, such that the text is only visible when the circle associated with the text has been clicked.

What would be the best approach to create this curve? For future design reference, I would like the circles to change size when one has been clicked and the others fade (Not expected to be answered here, just for design reference)

Comment: Could you please provide an example @RitambharDas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, if it ever arrives, the css `shape-inside` property is supposed to solve this problem. (See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shapes-2/) In the meantime, here is a proposed solution. I am using html to create li classes and using css to style the margin-left property of each bullet. I can then use classes to simulate a gentle curve in one direction and repeat each class on the other side to simulate the other half of the curve. You can tweak the margin-left values according to your needs. You mention that margins do not work for you, but I wonder if that's because of some aspect of your code I'm not seeing, as my version works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.a {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.b {
  margin-left: 23px;
}
.c {
  margin-left: 18px;
}
.d {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li class="a">Coffee</li>
  <li class="b">Tea</li>
  <li class="c">Coca Cola</li>
  <li class="d">Sprite</li>
  <li class="d">Something else</li>
  <li class="c">Other text</li>
  <li class="b">Espresso</li>
  <li class="a">Root beer</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a fiddle with the same css/html https://jsfiddle.net/L2o8cfv5/

To change size on click, you can have jquery change the margin-left property for each class and/or change the margin-top property to make the circle appear to grow.

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I must have been placing margins in the wrong place.

Comment: Remember, the <ul> element and each <li> have their own margins. Will you accept the answer?